# Nested Type Parameters in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter, nested-generics

This is an example which I made up to be a simplification of my real code, so I apologize if it is a little contrived. What I would like to do is to effectively get two type parameters out of a single nested type argument. I'm pretty sure this is impossible, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

```
//Not legal java code
public class Foo<C extends Collection<T>> { //where T is another type parameter
    private C coll;

    public Foo(C coll) {
        this.coll = coll;
    }

    public void add(T elem){
        this.coll.add(elem);
    }
    //UPDATED TO ADD GETTER
    /**
     * I may need to retrieve the collection again, or pass it
     * on to another function that needs the specific C type
     */
    public C getColl(){
        return coll;
    }
}
...
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
Foo<List<String>> foo = new Foo<List<String>>(strings);
foo.add("hello");
```

I know that I could do it by adding another type parameter:

```
public class Foo<C extends Collection<T>,T>
```

but then I have to add the redundant:

```
Foo<List<String>,String> foo = new Foo<List<String>,String>(strings);
```

And in my real world case, my generics can sometimes be specified in the implements clause like

```
public class Bar implements Baz<String>
```

Having to specify that second type parameter is even more painful then, because it feels like it throws the implementation details in my face. Having to say

```
Foo<Bar,String>
```

when there is a relationship between String and Bar already, just seems inelegant. I get that its Java, so that goes with the territory, but just curious if there was a solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible and I don't think it's ideal anyway because there is nothing in your existing class that requires invariance.

```
Foo<T,C extends Collection<T>>
```

could more generally be

```
Foo<T,C extends Collection<? super T>>
```

if the only reason to have T is to allow mutation of the collection.

Note, if you're concerned about having to specify two type parameters frequently, you can create a shallow subclass:

```
class DerivedFoo<T> extends Foo<Collection<T>,T>
```

and you can use factory methods to avoid having to double-specify at creation time

```
public static <T> Foo<Collection<T>,T> fromCollection(Collection<T> c)
```

You can also abstract the interface into an `interface` to get the benefits of concise types that you get with `DerivedFoo` above.

Comment: The factory method idea is interesting, but it still bothers me that the type is specified twice even though my code dictates that they always be the same.

Comment: @RusselLeggett, ok, so you do need invariance then, no `Collection<? super T>`?  Yep.  That's a pain.  My advice would be to deal with the complexity in your library and try to expose terse APIs by having factories whose return type is `interface Foo<T> extends ComplicatedFoo<CollectionSubType<T>,T>` so that clients can just use the single parameter version.

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you just use T as your only type parameter, as in:

```
public class Foo<T> { //where T is another type parameter
private Collection<T> coll;

public Foo(Collection<T> coll) {
    this.coll = coll;
}

public void add(T elem){
    this.coll.add(elem);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to see why this wouldn't be the solution as well.

Comment: As I said, it's a contrived example, but what if the type of collection that went in mattered as well. It could be a list or a set or a TreeList. Let's say I added a getter to retrieve the collection again - the type would matter.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Java7, constructors don't do type inference, the workaround is to have a static factory method. That's no longer necessary. In Java 7 you can

```
Foo<List<String>,String> foo = new Foo<>(strings);
```

Regarding `T` and `C`, if we have 2 type parameters with constraints between them, there got to be some degree of redundancy. In your example, since one parameter `C` totally dictates the another parameter `T`, the redundancy seems unbearable. I don't see a solution.

But you probably can feel better if the type parameters are reordered

```
Foo<String,Bar> foo = new Foo<>(bar);
```

so we declare `String` first; then further provide a `Baz<String>` which is `Bar`